# How do I set a variable to a function that gets input from the user in Racket?

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

I'm trying to make a program that takes user input at a variety of steps. In the beginning of the program, the player names themselves through an external function that should return a player object, which will be referenced many times later.

```
#lang racket


(define player
 (class object%
  (init-field
   name
   money
   lives
   health)
   (super-new)

(define/public (get-money)
  money)
)
)
;None of this function runs/the user is never prompted...
(define (start-game)
  (print "What do you want to name yourself?")
  (define name (read-line))
  (define start-mon (random 1000 5000))
  (print "You're starting with ")
  (print start-mon)
  (print " dollars.")
  (new player [name name]
             [money 0]
             [lives 2]
             [health 100])
)

(define (main)
  (define player start-game)
  (let/ec break
    (let loop ()
      (print ":")
      (define input (read-line))
  (cond [(string=? input "health") (send player get-health)]
        [(string=? input "exit")  (break)]
        [else  (print "sorry, command not recognized. Type help for commands.")])
  (loop)))
  (print "exiting..."))

(main)
```

My question is, how do I correctly assign the player variable to the return object of the function start-game, while letting that whole function execute and prompt the user?

Thank you!

Comment: What happens if you used `(define player (start-game))`?

Comment: Nothing. None of the print statements run.

Comment: @no_parachute44 Works for me if I add those parentheses. (And then there's a contract violation on `random`, which suggests that you haven't read the documentation for `random`.)

Comment: I don't think you have actually run the fixed code, where `start-game` is actually called, because it works.